# Incorrect results in GA4 reporting API for current day

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Strange one, in the GA4 reporting API, If I look for the previous day the numbers look about right. However, if I want to get screenPageViews and activeUsers for the current point today, the numbers are way off.

Has anyone encountered this and managed to find a solution, at this point in time I just assume that "today" as a start and end date doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GA4 free, The standard Intraday query from [data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) typically takes 4-8 hrs for the [data freshness](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en), which means the data you get from the API will not be accurate for the current(today) date at a point in time. For premium GA4, the ranges differ and fresh data is available a bit early.

Also, note that the [SLA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12233314?sjid=2847522526532798650-AP#data-processing) may not cover every report query.

[image]

---

Usually, as a best practice, it is advised not to include today's date (current date) while using the API

Answer (score 0):

The GA4 api to extract data from a GA4 google analytics account is called the Data api.  The reporting api was the api used to extract data from a universal analytics account.

You should know that Google analytics data is not live data with the data api for that you need to make a request to the real time report.  It is best to wait 24 to 48 hours before checking data to take into account for data latency.

[image]

Note: the time it takes for your data to complete processing depends upon the report you are requesting, as well as what dimensions and metrics and the amount of data in your system.  If you do try the real-time report you should know that it offers a very limited amount of data.